# IllegalStateException:STREAM when calling response.getWriter

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, httpresponse, illegalstateexception

This is a method that's used for handle ajax request. So the output is written to the `response`

```
public ModelAndView myAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception
{
    //call other methods and send the response as arg
    //call getWriter on the response
}
```

According to [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29), I would definitely have an IllegalStateException if I call getWriter having already called getOutputStream(), so I suspect the methods I passed the response to did this although I don't really see them doing so...
The only thing for sure is that at some point, one of the methods may do response.sendError().
Does this some how call getOutputStream()?

Comment: Show us the `ModelAndView` you return and if it maps to some other resource, a `jsp` for example.

Comment: I supposed it doesn't have to be a `ModelAndView`. I can very well replace it by `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HttpServletResponse#sendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29) commits the response and send an error status code. The javadoc states

> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be
>   considered to be committed and should not be written to.

In other words, after you call that method, the HTTP response has basically been sent. It makes no sense to call any of the `getOutputStream()` or `getWriter()` methods. Your `Servlet` container further makes it foolproof by throwing an Exception if you attempt to.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but I had not called sendError(), just setContentType() before that. As per [this source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/siwO-JRggrA), it can trigger the same behaviour:

> I am guessing its because you have already opened the stream by 
>   calling the resp.setContentType("text/plain"); method, and are then 
>   trying to get a Writer object. You can either use Stream based 
>   classes, or Writer based classes - not both.
>
> Either remove the setContentType(), or send the response using 
>   response.getOutputStream() method. That should solve the problem.

And indeed, it resolved the similar error for me.